# How to Paraphrase a narration which is written by a first person perspective

Tags: formatting

If teacher asks you to paraphrase a paragraph which is like "I went there etc" then how will we paraphrase it? Will it be like "The writer made his way to that place" or I'll be like it's me who is writing and paraphrase it like "I made my way to that place"?

Comment: The question is not very clear, because "paraphrase" means something more generic than what you mean. "To paraphrase" means "to express a certain phrase with different words". So it doesn't concern the POV, the person involved, etc. If the phrase is just "I went there", what you want is to use different words to express the same meaning, i.e. "I walked to that place".

Comment: Do you mean "summarize"? If you are just rewording it, I would do it from the same POV, your second option: "I made my way..."

Answer (score 4):

If the point of view is the same in the two types of narration, then keep it so. If it changes, then adapt the text accordingly.

In your example, if you wish to rewrite:

`I went there.`

and keep the same point of view, then

`I made my way to that place.`

If instead you wish to change the point of view

`The narrator made his/her way to that place.`

Answer (score 2):

If rewording is indeed what's needed, then @NofP gives a good answer.

However, what I take from your question, and the request from the teacher, is that maybe it's about the way you tell the reader something, without simply telling them "I went there.".

Perhaps the teacher believes that 'the reader' doesn't like when something is stated so simply.

- Maybe that sentence seems superfluous as is?
- Maybe it needs'something more'?

I do not by principle agree that such a sentence is automatically one of the above, but we can always express something differently.

**So how can we tell the reader that "I went there", in a different way?**

**Add something more**

> "On the way to the restaurant, the rain seemed to slow down the busy streets,
>   leaving some people seemingly calmed by it and others stressed. I was glad I wore the orange raincoat."

**Tell the reader indirectly; 'I went there'**

> "I heard the raindrops on my bedroom window, so I grabbed the orange raincoat, just in case. When I arrived at the restaurant, I found Laura by the first table, wearing what looked like a post-trauma blanket, as if someone had tried to drown her on the way there. Poor thing."

These are, of course, examples made with no knowledge of the story or the characters in your story. They serve to show how you can tell the reader something while focusing on something else, something (perhaps) more relevant or interesting to the reader.